# Error: toNetInput - expected media to be of type HTMLImageElement | HTMLVideoElement | HTMLCanvasElement | tf.Tensor3D, or to be an element id

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, face-api

I am trying to use Face-Api-js into the firebase cloud function. However, i keep getting the error which i can not understand. Moreover, i've tried to provide it base64 String as well but still i face some errors. Now, is there a way to make this happen or face-api-js just works for the html tags?

```
    /* eslint-disable */

     const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const fetch = require('node-fetch');
      const { createCanvas, Image } = require('canvas');

    // Import required libraries from face-api.js
     require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
    const faceapi = require('face-api.js');

   // Initialize Firebase Admin SDK
    admin.initializeApp();

exports.performFacialRecognitionOnCreate =                  functions.firestore.document('Access/{docId}').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
  try {
// Get the URL of the image file from 'picUrl' field in newly created document
const picUrl = snapshot.data().picUrl;

// Load models and weights for face detection and recognition using face-api.js
await Promise.all([
  faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromDisk('./assets/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromDisk('./assets/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromDisk('./assets/models')
]);

// Fetch image data from provided URL using node-fetch package
const response = await fetch(picUrl);

// Convert downloaded image data into a Buffer using Buffer.from()
  const imgBuffer = await response.buffer();

// Save downloaded image as JPEG file with fs.writeFile()
  fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/image.jpg', imgBuffer);
  
  // Create an HTMLImageElement instance with canvas package's Image class 
  const imgElm = new Image();

  // Set the source of the image to the saved JPEG file
  imgElm.src = '/tmp/image.jpg';
  
const canvas = createCanvas(imgElm.width, imgElm.height);
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.drawImage(imgElm, 0, 0);

  // Perform facial detection on input image using face-api.js methods
const detectedFaces =
  await faceapi.detectAllFaces(canvas).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceDescriptors();

if (detectedFaces.length === 0) {
  console.log('No faces detected in the input image.');
  
  // Update 'status' field of the newly created document to 'notFound'
  await snapshot.ref.update({ status: "notFound" });
  
  return null;
}

console.log(`Found ${detectedFaces.length} face(s) in the input image.`);

  // Get a reference to the 'DB' collection
  const dbCollectionRef = admin.firestore().collection('DB');

// Process each detected face and compare it with all documents in 'DB' collection
for (const detectedFace of detectedFaces) {
  for await (const docSnapshot of dbCollectionRef.get()) {
    const docData = docSnapshot.data();
    
    // Skip documents that don't have an 'imageLink' field or already matched.
    if (!docData.imageLink || docData.status === "found") continue;

    // Fetch stored image data from Firebase Storage URL specified by 'imageLink'
    const response2 = await fetch(docData.imageLink);
    
        // Convert downloaded existing image data into a Buffer using Buffer.from()
      const existingImgBuffer = await response2.buffer();
      
      // Save downloaded existing image as JPEG file with fs.writeFile()
      fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/existingImage.jpg', existingImgBuffer);

        // Create an HTMLImageElement instance for existing image
      const existingImgElm = new Image();
      
      // Set the source of the image to the saved JPEG file
      existingImgElm.src = '/tmp/existingImage.jpg';

    const existingCanvas = createCanvas(existingImgElm.width, existingImgElm.height);
    const ctxExisting = existingCanvas.getContext('2d');

    ctxExisting.drawImage(existingImgElm, 0, 0);

        // Perform facial recognition on current detected face and existing image
        const queryFaceDescriptor =
          await faceapi.computeFaceDescriptor(detectedFace);
        const results =
          await faceapi.detectSingleFace(existingCanvas).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceDescriptor();

      if (!results) continue;

        // Compare the computed descriptor with the descriptors of each detected face in 'DB' collection
        const distance = faceapi.euclideanDistance(queryFaceDescriptor, results.descriptor);

        // If match found, update 'status' field of the newly created document to 'found'
      if (distance < 0.6) {
      console.log('Match found!');
      
      // Get the corresponding Uid from matched document in 'DB' collection
      const uid = docSnapshot.id;
      
      // Update 'status' field and store matched Uid in the newly created document.
        await snapshot.ref.update({ status: "found", Uid: uid });
          
          return null; // Stop further processing as a match is found.
      }
  }
}

console.log('No matching faces found.');

// Update 'status' field of the newly created document to 'notFound'
await snapshot.ref.update({ status: "notFound" });

  return null;

 } catch (error) {
  console.error('Error during facial recognition:', error);
  throw error;
   }
  });
```

the Error output is:

```
Error: toNetInput - expected media to be of type HTMLImageElement | HTMLVideoElement | HTMLCanvasElement | tf.Tensor3D, or to be an element id
    at /workspace/node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/dom/toNetInput.js:38:35
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/dom/toNetInput.js:33:32)
    at step (/workspace/node_modules/face-api.js/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:141:27)
    at Object.next (/workspace/node_modules/face-api.js/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:122:57)
    at /workspace/node_modules/face-api.js/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:115:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (/workspace/node_modules/face-api.js/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:111:16)
    at Object.toNetInput (/workspace/node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/dom/toNetInput.js:17:20)
    at SsdMobilenetv1.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/ssdMobilenetv1/SsdMobilenetv1.js:55:52)
```

Comment: I'm guessing here, but I'm pretty sure its because you are using `canvas`, which is a Node package that can draw images using a canvas, but is not a `HTMLCanvasElement`. You might have to switch out for the `jsdom` library, create one of its canvas elements, draw on that and then feed the result to `face-api.js`.